# What is the best way to fetch data in react as chain where the second fetch depends on the data from the first fetch?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am building a react app with a Firebase backend and I am stuck on fetching data in multiple steps where I use data from the first fetch as a parameter for data from the second fetch.

Below is my code:

```
  // GET DATA FROM FIRESTORE 
  const { getQrCode, getBranch } = DatabaseService();
```

This is how I fetch the first data. I have the ID in this case.

```
  // GET QR CODE 
  const fetchQRCode = async () => {
    const data = await getQrCode(id); //I have this ID
    setBranchQr(data);
  };
```

This is the second fetch that I need using the data from the first fetch:

```
  // GET BRANCH DATA
  const fetchBranchData = async () => {
    const data = await getBranch(branchQr.branchId); //I get this from the first fetch
    setBranchData(data);
    console.log(data)
  };
```

These are the useEffects:

```
   useEffect(() => {
    fetchQRCode();
    fetchBranchData();
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
    }, []);
  useEffect(() => {}, [branchQr, branchData]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like said by Pooria, I would use Tanstack Queries

Install it using npm or yarn:

```
npm i @tanstack/react-query
```

Import it to your root JS file:

```
import { QueryClientProvider, QueryClient } from "@tanstack/react-query";
```

Create the client

```
  const queryClient = new QueryClient();
```

Wrap your root app

```
    <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>

    </QueryClientProvider>
```

Import your useQuery

```
import { useQuery } from "@tanstack/react-query";
```

Get the first set of data

```
      const { data: nameThatMakesSenseToYou } = useQuery({
    queryFn: () =>  getQrCode(id),
    queryKey: ["qrcode"],
  });
```

Create the branch ID from that first set of data

```
  const branchId = nameThatMakesSenseToYou.branchId;
```

Get the second set of data:

```
  const { status, data: branches } = useQuery({
    queryKey: ["branch", branchId],
    queryFn: () => getBranch(branchId),
    enabled: !!branchId,
  });
```

If you logged branches, you should see the data you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Your approach seems to be problem-free. I usually use `react-query` to handle fetch requests because it simplifies the process and makes it straightforward. With `react-query`, there's no need to manually use setState or other React hooks like useEffect. Additionally, there's no need to set isLoading, and it offers a many tools to simplify the work.

I would recommend you to take a look at the `Dependent Queries` page of `react-query` at [this link](https://tanstack.com/query/latest/docs/react/guides/dependent-queries).

Here's a simple example of using `react-query` from the official website:

```js
// Get the user
const { data: user } = useQuery({
  queryKey: ['user', email],
  queryFn: getUserByEmail,
})

const userId = user?.id

// Then get the user's projects
const {
  status,
  fetchStatus,
  data: projects,
} = useQuery({
  queryKey: ['projects', userId],
  queryFn: getProjectsByUser,
  // The query will not execute until the userId exists
  enabled: !!userId,
})
```

Here is a step-by-step gruid:

1. **Install Tanstack Queries** using npm or yarn:

```bash
npm i @tanstack/react-query
yarn add @tanstack/react-query
```

2. Add it into your root js/ts react file like `index.tsx` or `App.tsx`:

```js
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { QueryClient, QueryClientProvider } from "@tanstack/react-query";
import App from "src/App";

const queryClient = new QueryClient({});

ReactDOM.render(
  <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
    <App />
  </QueryClientProvider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

3. In the component where you want the calls to be made, call the queries as follows:

```js
import { useQuery } from "@tanstack/react-query";


// It's better to use a const for queryKey in order to export and use in future as follows.
export const REACT_QUERY_GET_QR_CODE_KEY = "GET_QR_CODE_KEY";
export const REACT_QUERY_GET_BRANCH_QUERY_KEY = "GET_BRANCH_QUERY_KEY";


const { data: nameThatMakesSenseToYou } = useQuery({
    queryFn: () =>  getQrCode(id),
    queryKey: [REACT_QUERY_GET_QR_CODE_KEY],
});

const branchId = nameThatMakesSenseToYou?.branchId;

const { status, data: branches } = useQuery({
  queryKey: [REACT_QUERY_GET_BRANCH_QUERY_KEY, branchId],
  queryFn: () => getBranch(branchId),
  enabled: !!branchId,
});
```